# MySql Where-Subquery syntax error

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

This code worked in Sqlite which i have more experience with. I cant figure out whats wrong here. If it helps `SELECT 1 FROM Post WHERE body =  'a';` doesnt give me a syntax error but this does

```
select 1 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Post WHERE body = 'a' ) ;
```

code:

```
INSERT INTO `Post` (
`name`,
...
`date`) select 
@0,
...
@6 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Post WHERE body =  @7 )
```

error

```
near 'WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Post WHERE body =  'text' )' at line 15
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using dual as the dummy table in your select (see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)).

```
INSERT INTO `Post` (
`name`,
...
`date`) select 
@0,
...
@6 
FROM DUAL
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Post WHERE body =  @7 )
```

From the referenced link:

> You are allowed to specify DUAL as a
>   dummy table name in situations where
>   no tables are referenced:
>
> mysql> SELECT 1 + 1 FROM DUAL;
>           -> 2